# How to access ISession when registering for DI in mvc core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, simple-injector

I am using SimpleInjector for my DI in Mvc Core and I have a class that accepts ISession at the constructor.

`public SessionAppAdminAuthorization(ISession session)`

I need to register this at the DI configuration in `StartUp.Configure` method but I don't know how the get the scoped session variable.

```
container.Register<IAppAdminAuthorization>(() => {
    return new SessionAppAdminAuthorization([I Need the ISession]); },
    Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Comment: There is some context missing from this question. You need to describe where you need to get this `ISession` from.

Comment: At `StartUp.Configure` method, I updated the question.

Comment: What is preventing you from getting this `ISession` variable and what is `ISession`? Please show an example of how you would get/use this `ISession` without Simple Injector.

Comment: @Steven I think [this](http://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-session-storage-in-asp-net-core/) explains asp.net core `ISession`.

Comment: is this an NHibernate ISession? because NHibernate does not support .net core https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3807

Comment: @MenelaosVergis Write an `ISessionProvider` that you inject, which you can use to get an instance of `ISession`. It is 'runtime data' so you should not inject that, instead, inject something that can provide you with the runtime data.

Comment: `ISession` is the interface of `Session`, an equivalent to `HttpContext.Current.Session`. Unfortunately in mvc core this global variable doesn't exists. I just need a why to get this `Session` object and create my Injected class with the current scope session.

Comment: @MenelaosVergis According to the article-link I provided, you should be able to retrieve it at `HttpContext.Session`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET Core's `ISession` can be accessed through the `HttpContext.Session` property. Since `HttpContext` is runtime data, the `Session` is as well. [Runtime data should not be injected into your components' constructors](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99), so your `SessionAppAdminAuthorization` should not depend on `ISession` directly.

The simplest fix is to let `SessionAppAdminAuthorization` depend on `IHttpContextAccessor` instead and call `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session` later on. Example:

```
public class SessionAppAdminAuthorization : IAppAdminAuthorization
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

    public SessionAppAdminAuthorization(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    public void DoSomethingUseful() {
        if (this.accessor.HttpContext.Session.GetBoolean("IsAdmin")) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can make the registrations as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // You need to register IHttpContextAccessor.
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    // ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment e, ILoggerFactory f)
{
    container.RegisterSingleton(
        app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>());

    container.Register<IAppAdminAuthorization, SessionAppAdminAuthorization>();

    // ...
}
```

Although this will effectively solve your problem, you might want to take it up one step. In general it's better to hide framework components and abstractions like `IHttpContextAccessor`, `HttpContext` and `ISession` from application components. Instead the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) guides us towards application-specific abstractions implemented by adapters that allow translating these application-specific calls onto framework components. For instance:

```
// Application-specific abstraction (part of your application's core layer)
public interface IUserContext
{
    bool IsAdmin { get; }
}

// Adapter implementation (placed in the Composition Root of your web app)
public class AspNetSessionUserContextAdapter : IUserContext
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;
    public AspNetSessionUserContextAdapter(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    public bool IsAdmin => this.accessor.HttpContext.Session.GetBoolean("IsAdmin");
}

// Improved version of SessionAppAdminAuthorization
public class SessionAppAdminAuthorization : IAppAdminAuthorization
{
    private readonly IUserContext userContext;
    // This class can now be moved to the business layer, since there's no
    // more dependency on ASP.NET.
    public SessionAppAdminAuthorization(IUserContext userContext) {
        this.userContext = userContext;
    }

    public void DoSomethingUseful() {
        if (this.userContext.IsAdmin) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Registration:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment e, ILoggerFactory f)
{
    var accesr = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    container.RegisterSingleton<IUserContext>(new AspNetSessionUserContextAdapter(accesr));
    container.Register<IAppAdminAuthorization, SessionAppAdminAuthorization>();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, as I can see there is a wiring between SimpleInjection and Microsoft DI, I will try to implement the second example too. You are right it's not very elegant to include all these ms stuff in my libs.